# dpkg was interrupted. How do I do this? manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: dpkg

```
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.ntua.gr_pub_linux_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_i18n_Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ftp.ntua.gr_pub_linux_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_universe_i18n_Translation-en  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch ://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/testing-collection/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/testing-collection/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 75.76.44.43 80]
W: Failed to fetch ://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 75.76.44.43 80]
W: Failed to fetch ://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/gambas3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ://ppa.launchpad.net/nemh/gambas3/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When trying to pull up a simple command as such `sudo apt-get update` or trying to install certain normal things dpkg was interrupted,, shows it's self with out fail.

Comment: @Mr. Green, Thank you but as I have stated before that don't work. 
sudo dpkg --configure -a only shows errors nothing else. 

dpkg was interrupted. How do I do this?>> manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. (With out a smart ass answer or rude remarks please) " Thank you"

Comment: This is what works!
mime-support error! go to usr/share/applications and move the black box folder and any folder that doesn't belong there then just re-install mime-support and then put back the file you moved! this should fix that error.
if you like go to : var/lib/dpkg/info and locate mime support files and delete all of them then just open a terminal and do apt-get remove mine-support if this does not work try to remove it with synaptic and re-install it.
Finally remove the package libfreefare0 and re-install it !

I hope this helps other people facing the same minor error.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window (press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), and type in the line:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: when i run this not much seems to work and my ssh connection gets dropped

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience running this on a remote machine, but if the ssh mechanisms are being reconfigured that may explain why the ssh is being dropped.